# How can I avoid in-page Javascript and use external Javascript files, if all of my pages are different?

Tags: javascript

I have search a lot and found several methods about how to call page specific javascript with external files.

The best method i found is call one-line function in HTML page like

```
frontEnd.ContactPageLoad();
```

But this requires to have in-page javascript..

Other method is to have an id /attribute at body or at `<script> tag` and this to call what you want.

What should i do for this case?

**EDIT**
This is what i want.. 
http://paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/

Comment: You should choose the method you favour. Another option is to take a look at the url.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Perhaps you could give a more concrete example of what you'd like to do.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the problem i am trying to solve is how to avoid in page javascript and have only external. Then the problem is how can js know where it should start?

Comment: I edited your title.  Is that the question you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the way you formulated your question :

> how can js know where it should start?

Javascript is a scripting langage , it means it will evaluate line by line everything written in a script.

so if you put myFunction() at the beginning or the end of a file it doesnt matter , provided myFunction is defined. nothing requires to have javascript inside your html except a few framework perhaps.

write a a script called myscript.js then put a script tag in your html page :

```
<script src='myscript.js' type='text/javascript></script>
```

have you tried this ?